# Modify pdf file to have multiple slides per page

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file with 100 slides in it. I would like to send it to my IT department for printout (6 slides - double sided LANDSCAPE A4).

However they are finicky and always complain they don't have time to do all this and invariable end up printing them wrong.

Is there a way I can create a new pdf from this with 6 slides from the old pdf on every page of the new one so the only thing my IT would need to do is to print it?

I have the pro version of PDF-xchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I open it in adobe and choose print, I have a field that says "copies per page", which I can set to any perfect square between 1 and 16.

[image: Example]

You can always print to a pdf, instead of a printer :-)

Comment: We've all been there friend ;-)